# converting c for loop to fortran do loop

Tags: c++, loops, fortran

I am converting a cpp prog (from another author) to a Fortran prog, my C is not too strong.  I came across for-loop constructs starting with

```
for (int n = 1; 1; ++n) {
...
```

I would have expected this to convert to a Fortran Do as per

```
Do n=1, 1, 2
...
```

... at least that is my guess based on my understanding of what ++n will do.

Is my translation correct?  If so, the loop will cycle at most once, so what am I missing ???

I understand that in some ways c for-loops have a "do-while" aspect, and hence wrinkles porting to Fortran Do's.

Anyway ... a clarification would be much appreciated.

EDITED: after some prompt responses, and I think I see where this is going

First, the exact C code copy/paste but "trimming" a little, is

```
    for (int n = 1; 1; ++n) {
      const double coef = exp(-a2*(n*n)) * expx2 / (a2*(n*n) + y*y);
      prod2ax *= exp2ax;
      prodm2ax *= expm2ax;
      sum1 += coef;
      sum2 += coef * prodm2ax;
      sum4 += (coef * prodm2ax) * (a*n);
      sum3 += coef * prod2ax;
      sum5 += (coef * prod2ax) * (a*n);
      // test convergence via sum5, since this sum has the slowest decay
      if ((coef * prod2ax) * (a*n) < relerr * sum5) break;
    }
```

So yes, there is a "break" in the loop, which on the Fortran side is replaced with an "Exit".

I think the key seems to be from the answers below that the original code's author created the 
    for (int n=1; 1 ; ++n )
precisely to create a an infinite loop, and I had not guessed that this for construct would create an infinite loop.

Anyway, I can certainly create an infinite loop with an "Exit" in Fortran (though I expect I might "do" it a bit more judiciously)

Many thanks to all.

It seems the Mr Gregory's response was the one that imediately lead to a solution for me, so I will mark his correct.  As for the Fortran side, there are a number of alternatives such as:

```
  Do While
    :
    If( something ) Exit
  End Do
```

but being old fashioned I would probably use a construct with a "limit" such as

```
   Do i=1, MaxIter
    :
    If( something ) Exit
   End Do
```

For slightly fancier applications I might include a return flag in case it did not converge in MaxIter's etc.

Comment: Which Fortran? Fortran77, Fortran95, Fortran2005? And which C++? C++11? BTW, why do you convert it? Calling C++ code from Fortran might be simpler than  converting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what

```
for (int n = 1; 1; ++n)
```

does:

It sets `n` to 1, then loops infinitely, incrementing `n` by 1 at the end of each loop iteration. The loop will never terminate unless something inside the loop breaks out.

It's been a long time since I wrote Fortran but as I recall the `do` loop you translated it to is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to be definitive without seeing how the C++ program breaks out of that loop, but a straightforward Fortran equivalent would be

```
n = 1
do
    ! code, including an exit under some condition, presumably on the value of n
    n = n+1
end do
```

If the loop is terminated when `n` reaches a critical value then the equivalent might be

```
do n = 1, critical_value  ! no need to indicate step size if it is 1
    ! code
end do
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wrote the C code correctly? Typically loops in C/C++ are done like this:

```
for (int n = 1; n < 10; ++n) {
    // ...
}
```

Note the "n < 10" test condition. Your code's test condition is simply `1`, which will always evaluate to Boolean "true". This means the code will loop infinitely, unless there's a `break` inside the loop, which you haven't shown.

`++n` means "increment n".

So if the code you've shown is indeed correct, the FORTRAN equivalent would be:

```
n = 1
do
    [Body of the loop, which you haven't shown]
    n = n + 1
enddo
```

Comment: Okay, then ``do while ( .TRUE. )``?

Comment: Point taken, and I've edited my response. The larger picture here is not so much how to do a ``FOR`` loop in FORTRAN, but that the C loop shown by the OP is not a typical C ``for()`` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can translate

```
for (int n = 1; 1; ++n)
```

to a FORTRAN DO loop. From what I recall, the notion of the generic conditional in C/C++ cannot be emulated in a FORTRAN DO loop.

The equivalent of

```
Do n=1, 1, 2
```

in C/C++ is

```
for ( int n = 1; n <= 1; n += 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes in addition to CareyGregory’s answer.

`++n` means ‘increment n by one (before n is evaluated)’

In C and C++, a `for` loop has three clauses, much like in FORTRAN:

```
for (init; condition; increment)
```

The difference is that each of the clauses must be a complete expression, whereas in FORTRAN the clauses are just values. It is just a ‘short’ way of writing an equivalent `while` loop:

```
int n = 1;          │ for (int n = 1; 1; ++n)    │ n = 1
while (1)           │ {                          │ do 
{                   │   ...                      │   ...
  ...               │ }                          │   n = n + 1
  ++n;              │                            │ enddo
}                   │                            │
```